# Matching two date columns in a postgres query with multiple joined tables

Tags: postgresql

I am getting all of the information that I need from the following query:

```
SELECT
    o.id,
    o.customer_context,
    o.organization_name,
    o.shipping_name,
    o.shipping_street1,
    o.shipping_city,
    o.shipping_state,
    o.shipping_postal_code,
    order_total,
    shipping_charge,
    sales_tax_charge,
    discount_amount,
    charge_date,
    ship_date,
    o.email,
    shipping_country,
    c.status,
    c.unsubscribe,
    c.last_logon,
    c.last_action,
    c.full_name AS customer_name,
    c.email AS customer_email,
    c.billing_email AS customer_billing_email,
    c.organization_name AS customer_org_name,
    c.phone AS customer_phone,
    li.valid_from_dt,
    li.valid_thru_dt,
    pr.name,
    sum(wi.order_qty) AS printed_book_count
FROM
    online_order_onlineorder AS o
    LEFT OUTER JOIN online_order_weborderitem AS wi ON (wi.web_order_id = o.id
        AND format = 'PRT')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN customer_customer AS c ON (c.id = o.customer_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN customer_customer_curriculum_license AS li ON (li.customer_id = c.id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN product_curriculumlicense AS pli ON (pli.product_ptr_id = li.license_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN product_product AS pr ON (pr.id = pli.product_ptr_id)
WHERE
    o.status in('F', 'FF')
    AND o.charge_date >= '2019-03-05'
    AND o.charge_date < '2020-10-05'
GROUP BY
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28
ORDER BY
    charge_date,
    shipping_name
```

The only problem is that I can not get the `o.charge_date` to match the `li.valid_from_dt`

I have tried adding comparison operators such as:

```
WHERE
    o.status in('F', 'FF')
    AND o.charge_date >= '2019-03-05'
    AND o.charge_date < '2020-10-05'
    AND li.valid_from_dt >= '2019-03-05'
    AND li.valid_from_dt < '2020-10-05'
```

but as expected it just limits the pool of `li.valid_from_dt` and still doesn't match up with `o.charge_date` I also need to account for the fact that certain orders will have `NULL` for the `li.valid_from_dt`

The only relations between `o.charge_date` and `li.valid_from_dt` is that they both share a relation with the `c.id` is there some way to bring these tables together to match the two dates, and keep the all of the other data the same?

I have spent a while working on this and any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Additional info, here is an example of the `customer_customer_curriculum_license` table from the same customer.

| id | valid_from_dt | valid_thru_dt | created_on | updated_on | purchase_price | max_head_count | customer_id | license_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2262 | 2014-06-03 | 2015-06-03 | 2015-06-24 18:35:36.884+00 | 2015-07-01 21:43:55.125+00 | 440.00 | 29 | 4178 | 1 |
| 2263 | 2014-06-03 | 2015-06-03 | 2015-06-24 18:35:36.888+00 | 2015-07-01 21:43:55.128+00 | 440.00 | 19 | 4178 | 17 |
| 2264 | 2014-06-03 | 2015-07-13 | 2015-06-24 18:35:36.891+00 | 2015-06-29 21:55:30.095+00 | 440.00 | 29 | 4178 | 13 |
| 2265 | 2014-06-03 | 2015-07-13 | 2015-06-24 18:35:36.894+00 | 2015-06-29 21:54:16.496+00 | 440.00 | 19 | 4178 | 20 |
| 2266 | 2014-06-03 | 2015-07-13 | 2015-06-24 18:35:36.897+00 | 2015-07-01 21:43:55.126+00 | 440.00 | 29 | 4178 | 14 |
| 2267 | 2014-06-03 | 2015-07-13 | 2015-06-24 18:35:36.901+00 | 2015-06-29 21:41:29.784+00 | 440.00 | 29 | 4178 | 16 |

And an example of the `online_order_onlineorder` table.

| id | status | customer_context | email | phone | billing_name | billing_street1 | billing_street2 | billing_state | billing_city | billing_postal_code | shipping_name | shipping_street1 | shipping_street2 | shipping_state | shipping_city | shipping_postal_code | order_total | shipping_charge | sales_tax_rate | sales_tax_charge | discount_amount | authorization_code | reference_number | transaction_id | created_on | updated_on | ship_date | charge_date | is_shipped | tracking_number | applied_offer_id | customer_id | billing_country | shipping_country | shipping_option_id | shipping_weight | customer_name | organization_contact | organization_name | gift_message | is_gift |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 418 | FF | O | example@example.com |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00000 | 0.00 | 0.00 |  |  |  | 2012-06-28 05:00:00+00 | 2015-06-24 18:40:55.194+00 |  |  | f |  |  | 4177 |  | US |  | 0.00 |  |  |  |  | f |
| 420 | FF | O | example@example.com |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00000 | 0.00 | 0.00 |  |  |  | 2012-07-05 05:00:00+00 | 2015-06-24 18:40:55.214+00 |  |  | f |  |  | 4177 |  | US |  | 0.00 |  |  |  |  | f |

The only related field between the two tables is `customer_id` and I need to match the `o.charge_date` and the `li.valid_from_dt` with the same `o.customer_id` to get the date when they purchased and when the license started that same day per each order.

My Results, as you can see the customer ordered `2019-03-05 16:02:24.10583+00`, but the `valid_from_dt` is incorrect, it should be the same date the customer ordered.

| id | customer_context | organization_name | shipping_name | shipping_street1 | shipping_city | shipping_state | shipping_postal_code | order_total | shipping_charge | sales_tax_charge | discount_amount | charge_date | ship_date | email | shipping_country | status | unsubscribe | last_logon | last_action | customer_name | customer_email | customer_billing_email | customer_org_name | customer_phone | valid_from_dt | valid_thru_dt | name | printed_book_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 33733 | O | None | John Doe | 111 test | Test | HI | 99999 | 180.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 2019-03-05 16:02:24.10583+00 |  | example@example.com | United States (Domestic And Apo/Fpo/Dpo Mail) | O | f | 2020-08-19 13:49:26.338082+00 | None | John Doe | example@example.com |  |  |  | 2017-04-25 | 2018-04-24 | Valid for 365 Days |  |

Comment: You haven't actually explained what you are trying to match. Are you just wanting something like `o.charge_date BETWEEN li.valid_from_dt AND lt.valid_thru_dt`?

Comment: Sorry, I need the `o.charge_date` associated with the `li.valid_from_dt`. If a user places an order for a license, the dates should match up from `o.charge_date` and `li.vali_from_dt`.

For example, I have a record where `o.charge_date = 2019-03-05 16:02:24.10583+00` and the `li.valid_from_dt = 2018-04-25`. This is not correct.

Now that I think of it, my current query could be grabbing `li.valid_from_dt` from other customers orders. The issue is that it seems like `o.charge_date` is associated correctly with all other entries, but `li.valid_from_dt` is just randomly thrown in.

Comment: Your example data doesn't have any values for `charge_date` so none of them can match. You won't be mixing up `li` rows with `o` rows from other customers because you link them through `c`. I think what you want to do is figure out exactly what the relationship is betwen `o.charge_date` (which you treat as a timestamp in the comment above) and `li.valid_from_dt` (which you show as an actual date in your example data). Then write that into your query.

Comment: The example data is blank, but I included it to show the table column names, there is actual data in the tables from the database. Yes, the `charge_date` is a timestamp and the `valid_from_dt` is the date.

I have also tried `LEFT OUTER JOIN customer_customer_curriculum_license AS li ON (li.customer_id = o.customer_id)`

Added an example of the result of my query with user data scrubbed, you can see the dates don't match.

Comment: "The example data is blank" - well no, all the columns we aren't interested in have data in. "you can see the dates don't match", well (1) `charge_date` isn't a date - you just said it is a timestamp - how can a timestamp match a date and (2) if you don't add any restrictions in your where clause (as I've suggested twice now) why would you expect them to?

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the much appreciated help from Richard Huxton, I have settled with the following SQL query.

EDITED, the previous query had an issue. The following is the correct query to use. I converted both `o.charge_date` and `li.valid_from_dt` using `::date`, I was then able to match on the exact data that I needed!

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (o.id)
    o.id,
    o.customer_context,
    o.organization_name,
    o.shipping_name,
    o.shipping_street1,
    o.shipping_city,
    o.shipping_state,
    o.shipping_postal_code,
    order_total,
    shipping_charge,
    sales_tax_charge,
    discount_amount,
    charge_date,
    ship_date,
    o.email,
    shipping_country,
    c.status,
    c.unsubscribe,
    c.last_logon,
    c.last_action,
    c.full_name AS customer_name,
    c.email AS customer_email,
    c.billing_email AS customer_billing_email,
    c.organization_name AS customer_org_name,
    c.phone AS customer_phone,
    li.valid_from_dt,
    li.valid_thru_dt,
    pr.name,
    sum(wi.order_qty) AS printed_book_count
FROM
    online_order_onlineorder AS o
    LEFT OUTER JOIN online_order_weborderitem AS wi ON (wi.web_order_id = o.id
        AND format = 'PRT')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN customer_customer AS c ON (c.id = o.customer_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN customer_customer_curriculum_license AS li ON (li.valid_from_dt::date = o.charge_date::date)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN product_curriculumlicense AS pli ON (pli.product_ptr_id = li.license_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN product_product AS pr ON (pr.id = pli.product_ptr_id)
WHERE
    o.status in('F', 'FF')
    AND o.charge_date >= '2019-03-05'
    AND o.charge_date < '2020-10-05'
GROUP BY
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10,
    11,
    12,
    13,
    14,
    15,
    16,
    17,
    18,
    19,
    20,
    21,
    22,
    23,
    24,
    25,
    26,
    27,
    28
ORDER BY
    id,
    charge_date,
    shipping_name
```